# why does not btt in blktrace tool report any data

Tags: linux, performance, io, block-device, blktrace

The `btt` report is as below：

```
/ssd/blktrace/btt/btt -i parse.bin
==================== All Devices ====================

            ALL           MIN           AVG           MAX           N
--------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -----------


==================== Device Overhead ====================

       DEV |       Q2G       G2I       Q2M       I2D       D2C
---------- | --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------

==================== Device Merge Information ====================

       DEV |       #Q       #D   Ratio |   BLKmin   BLKavg   BLKmax    Total
---------- | -------- -------- ------- | -------- -------- -------- --------

==================== Device Q2Q Seek Information ====================

       DEV |          NSEEKS            MEAN          MEDIAN | MODE
---------- | --------------- --------------- --------------- | ---------------

==================== Device D2D Seek Information ====================

       DEV |          NSEEKS            MEAN          MEDIAN | MODE
---------- | --------------- --------------- --------------- | ---------------

==================== Plug Information ====================

       DEV |    # Plugs # Timer Us  | % Time Q Plugged
---------- | ---------- ----------  | ----------------

       DEV |    IOs/Unp   IOs/Unp(to)
---------- | ----------   ----------

==================== Active Requests At Q Information ====================

       DEV |  Avg Reqs @ Q
---------- | -------------

==================== I/O Active Period Information ====================

       DEV |     # Live      Avg. Act     Avg. !Act % Live
---------- | ---------- ------------- ------------- ------
---------- | ---------- ------------- ------------- ------
 Total Sys |          0   0.000000000   0.000000000   0.00
```

I expect `btt` could report data, but it did not.

Comment: did you check `man btt` or `btt --help` (etc)? Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming problems. Your question may be more suitable for [su] or [unix.se], but please read their help sections concerning "how-to-ask" and on-topic questions. Good luck.